# Crash in react-native android app

Tags: android, react-native

I have been experiencing a crash in my react native android app with the following call stack

```
02-24 12:38:35.799 2878-2878/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.myapp, PID: 2878
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewsInternal(ViewGroup.java:4300)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4156)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.updateSubviewClipStatus(ReactViewGroup.java:307)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.updateClippingToRect(ReactViewGroup.java:283)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.updateClippingRect(ReactViewGroup.java:276)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.updateClippingRect(ReactScrollView.java:220)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.onScrollChanged(ReactScrollView.java:152)
                                                                 at android.widget.ScrollView.onOverScrolled(ScrollView.java:801)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollView.onOverScrolled(ReactScrollView.java:341)
                                                                 at android.view.View.overScrollBy(View.java:18607)
                                                                 at android.widget.ScrollView.computeScroll(ScrollView.java:1293)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14154)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
                                                                 at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
                                                                at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279
02-24 12:38:43.283 2878-2878/com.myapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2878 SIG: 9
```

The abort is intermittent with no set steps to reproduce. If anyone else has experienced similar crash on Android, please share if you have more information.

Thanks!

Comment: A log means nothing without code to compare it to. See [mcve]

Comment: debug js code no simulator it provides complete message in console

Comment: @NickCardoso Like I said, I am not sure where the abort is happening. It is happening intermittently and I wouldn't know which part of the code to share.

Comment: @VarunGupta did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with ListView:

> Set ListView's `removeClippedSubviews` to `false` can prevent the crash

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11825

Comment: I will give it a try and check if I continue to see the abort. I checked the github issue that you have mentioned and the call stack appears to be a little different as compared to mine. There, the users are experiencing IndexOutOfBounds exception and I am observing NullPointerException but it could still be related. Thanks.